# Programmatic access to shell expansion, substitution, and word splitting

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, posix

I want to make `exec()` calls with some amount of shell functionality. Given a string naming a shell, a string naming an executable, and a string representing a command line, how can I generate an array of strings that are the arguments that the shell would pass to the executable?

So on my machine, for the shell string `"bash"`, the executable string `"tr"`, and the command line string `"tr 'hi there' goodbye"`, I'd like to generate the array `{"tr", "hi there", "goodbye"}`.

Many basic shell features, like the word splitting example above, aren't terribly difficult to emulate. Still, it would be preferable to directly determine how a shell on the current machine would behave.

I don't simply want to run a shell command. I want to retain control of the rest of the execution context, for example, file descriptors.

Specifically, I'm interested in if there is a simple way to apply brace expansion, tilde expansion, variable expansion, word splitting, filename expansion, and quote removal.

I'm not asking how to implement a shell. My question is if there's a system call on linux platforms to just do these things or any other way to programmatically access the command line parsing of a shell.

The goal is to create a program that will be given a string that specifies an executable to run and the arguments for that executable. The program will run the specific executable by fork and exec then communicate with it through stdin and stdout. This question is only asking about the handling of the string that specifies the executable and arguments. Is there a simple way to parse a command line string as a shell would?

To get shell command line parsing functionality, it is possible to feed shell scripts or "sh -c " style commands to the program. However, if there exists a system functionality to parse a command line and make the result viewable programmatically that would be preferable. Does that exist? If so, what is it?

The target OS is linux. The shell of primary interest is bash. Portability is preferable but not necessary.

Comment: Are you saying you want to emulate all the complex substitution that a typical shell does?  That will basically involve writing most of a shell (or finding a library that does it for you).  (Not my downvote, BTW...)

Comment: I'm asking how I can avoid emulating a shell. I want to know if there's a way to determine how a shell would interpret a command line.

Comment: Why do you want to *exactly emulate* a shell? Why not some better scripting language?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: Ok, so you need to find a library/util of some kind that does the work for you.  There's no way of knowing what `foo $(find . -name "*bar*") $(groups)` etc. etc. will evaluate to without actually evaluating it.  (But I'm afraid I don't know of such a library off-hand.)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The intent is specifically for a parent process to access some other executable that becomes known at run time. This isn't meant for scripting. Having shell features would simply be nice and for all I know there might be an easy way to just ask bash to parse a string.

Comment: Then edit your question to improve it. Give some usage example. I can't understand what you exactly mean by "having shell features"

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If there were an easy way to get everything short of command substitution that would be fine too.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I was hoping there would be a way to do this for arbitrary shells with arbitrary features complying with a standard, maybe POSIX. That doesn't seem to be the case so I'll make the question more specific.

Comment: I still don't understand the question and what *really motivates* it. I gave some references in my answer, but I downvoted the question because it is extremely unclear. What are your exact goals? What is your software trying to achieve? Please *edit your question* to improve it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read first [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

<sup>Recall that shells are expanding -i.e. [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)- arguments like `*.txt` *before* doing the [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) functions.</sup>

In your C code, you could use [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) and/or [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) and even better [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html). For file descriptors, you'll need [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [dup(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) and many other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html).

To scan a file tree like [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) does use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html). To just read a directory, use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) etc...

At some point, you'll need to multiplex input (and/or output), so learn about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

For lexing a string in constituent parts, you might consider [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html).

Actually, it looks like you want to embed some [scripting interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) in your program. So consider [GNU guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile) or [lua](http://lua.org/) (and perhaps prefer some different syntax & scripting language than the one provided by the shell).

Alternately design your software as a library and code the necessary glue code to embed it inside an *existing* scripting interpreter (like [Python](http://python.org/), etc...) - or even (but I probably don't recommend that) as a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) to some existing shell.

BTW, [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) and [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) both fork a shell. You could build carefully their argument string. Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) so quote appropriately some arguments.

#### addenda

after your edit, you want `wordexp`. However, you should be careful, e.g. because some file names or directory names may contain spaces, and you need to parse these spaces as part of the name...

Comment: This is a very nice summary. wordexp is what I was after.

Comment: But you still need to be careful, e.g. if you have spaces in some directory name. Something has to parse the space correctly...

Comment: With gcc on a recent Ubuntu, wordexp() does globbing and appropriately handles filenames with spaces. It appropriately identifies them as a single token. Based on your comment, is that behavior not something I can rely on in general? It's not clear to me from the documentation.